# How do I use parameters for cron expressions in Nifi processors

Tags: apache-nifi

I would like to schedule processors using cron expressions defined in parameters that are passed as environment variables. However, regardless of how I define these environment variables, they end up with additional double quotes, resulting in errors.
I've tried several approaches, e.g.:

- `set ALERT_MAIL_CRON=0\ 8\ *\ *\ *\ ?`
- `set ALERT_MAIL_CRON=0 8 * * * ?`
- `set ALERT_MAIL_CRON="0 8 * * * ?"`

Nifi Version: 2.0.0-M1

OS: Windows 11

[image]

The error message:

```
Scheduling Period '#{ALERT_MAIL_CRON}' is not a valid cron expression: For input string: ""0" '"0' in cron expression ""0 8 * * * ?""
```

Comment: I do not think this is possible.  The CRON is not parsing it as expression language/variables/parameters.  It's just a literal string.

Comment: It's correct that you cannot use expression language, however the error message shows that the parameter was resolved, you can see the value. Also this code snippet shows me that it's intended to allow parameters: https://github.com/apache/nifi/blob/689f9909786d126843740f774e897f8bbd6a0e86/nifi-nar-bundles/nifi-framework-bundle/nifi-framework/nifi-framework-components/src/main/java/org/apache/nifi/controller/StandardProcessorNode.java#L1151C20-L1151C20

Comment: only parameters from "parameter context" are available to be used in cron expression

Comment: For some reason those parameters get double quotes. I've created the parameter context with an `EnvironmentVariableParameterProvider` (in ControllerSettings)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You both weren't wrong, but my issue was something else.
The environment variables don't synchronize into Parameter Contexts automatically on startup. On first setup of those environment variable parameter provider, parameters will be fetched from environment variables.

**On every startup you need to upate them manually by pressing the fetch and apply button**:
[image]

Comment: tbh, I'm missing the opt-in auto-refresh feature mentioned here: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/NIFI/Parameter+Providers%3A+Fetching+Parameters+from+External+Sources

Answer (score 2):

I was able to run the `GenerateFlowFile` processor by defining the cron expression under the Parameter context.

Please find below the configuration for your reference.

[image: Parameter Context]

[image: Processor Properties]

> The below is a GIF image so you would see the processor running and generating a flowfile

[image: Running Realtime]

Comment: I've assumed so, since the github link that I've referenced (in my comment above), shows that parameter context should work. However it doesn't work if you load the parameter context from environment variables. I guess it's a bug. Could you tell me which os you're using and if you've passed the parameter context as environment variable?

Comment: sorry for the delayed response, I tried this using the normal parameter context. If I get some time today will check out the environment variable option, cheers

Answer (score 1):

- windows 10
- nifi 1.24.0

The parameters defined with `EnvironmentVariableParameterProvider` working in `Run schedule`

Steps:

1. add environment variable `set ALERT_MAIL_CRON=* * * * * ?` and then start nifi from the context where variable is defined
2. after starting nifi goto `main sandwich menu -> Controller Settings-> Parameter Providers`
3. add new provider `EnvironmentVariableParameterProvider` and define which variables to import
   [image]
4. on the screen with "Parameter Providers" click the fetch button to import/preview parameter values
   [image]
5. now go to flow configuration and define `Process Group Parameter Context`
   [image]
6. finally the environment variable `ALERT_MAIL_CRON` must be visible for you as a parameter and you can use it in cron expression
   [image]